# Thermal pad to dissipate heat to pc case

Tags: heat, thermal, pc

My motherboard, at the back of the CPU to be precise, is quite hot. Mine is a X99 with little over clocking. I am thinking if I use a piece of adhesive silicone pad to transfer the heat from the back of the motherboard to the computer case helps to reduce to heat generated by the CPU and dissipate the heat to the side of my metal PC case?

Comment: How hot is “quite hot”? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Isn't the CPU air cooled, with a fan?

Comment: How about not overclocking the CPU so it does not heat up more than CPU and surrounding components are specified?

Comment: i dont have the tool so i dono how hot it is. my cpu's tdp is above 100 and with a corsair h115i and a total of 5 in 3 out pc fans, even in bios the temp can go as high as 45C, with room temp about 2xC. disable oc helps but only a bit

Comment: A CPU that reaches 45°C isn't hot at all and shouldn't be a cause for concern. Doesn't your OC software offer the possibility to check the temperature during normal operation?

Answer (score 2):

A thermal pad between the bottom of the mother board and the PC case probably won't do much.

Most CPUs for PCs are designed and packaged so that the most of the heat flows through the top of the package.  This is where the heat has to be removed from, and is the reason CPUs have heat sinks and/or fans or liquid cooling of some sort mounted to the top of the case.

A small amount of the CPUs total heat produced may make it to the mother board, but not enough that a thermal pad would make much difference.

A complete analysis would require using an EDA thermal analysis tool and modeling all the sources and sinks of the heat dissipated.

Answer (score 1):

From [the internet](https://pcper.com/2014/09/asus-x99-deluxe-motherboard-review/2/), the back of the motherboard looks like this:

[image]

I couldn't find any spec for the thermal resistance from CPU to board via the socket.

Likewise I have no idea what the metal plate at the back is made of, or if there is thermal interface material between it and the PCB to improve heat transfer. It looks riveted, so it's probably not possible to investigate.

So there's not much data.

It'll be difficult to apply force to squish the thermal pad between the back of the PCB and the heat sink so let's try a 5mm thick soft thermal pad. Say 4x4cm so it covers the back of the CPU.

Thermal conductivity: Tc about 3-4 W/m.K so let's go with 3.5.

Thermal resistance = thickness (in m) / (surface (in m²) x Tc) = 0.89°C/W

So due to the large area, even a thick soft thermal pad of relatively low thermal conductivity could provide a bit of cooling.

Then there is the case: if it is stamped sheet steel, then lateral conduction through it will be negligible, so the only meaningful cooling would be through the sheet steel and then contact with air. Due to the low surface area and absence of fins or fan, you're looking at (wet finger in the wind) maybe 10-20°C/W which pretty much sinks the entire project.

So you would need a fan, but in this case it would be better to go all the way and make a round hole in the case, and mount a fan blowing on the back of the motherboard (this will also cool the VRM and other stuff).

But the whole board isn't designed for this, it's designed to be cooled from the other side.

So IMO you'd be better off with a good case fan and good airflow in the case. If you reduce the air temperature in the case by 1°C, then the temperature of everything inside will also drop by 1°C.

Comment: The metal plate on the back is just for mounting the heatsink, it's probably steel and there's no thermal interface material.

Comment: thanks bobflux, you have provided me some useful info. but should it be 89 instead?  nevermind, i got you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The skin of the PC enclosure is not going to be nearly enough to remove the heat.

How do I know that? Because people have tried putting PCs in refrigerators and that doesn't work.  A refrigerator uses most of its exterior skin as the heat dump, and it can remove about 600 watts of heat with all that.   A single spot on the side of a PC case isn't even close.

You should use bog-standard methods for cooling CPUs, such as forced-air cooling across a heat sink, or if you want to get fancy, water cooling.

Note that automotive radiators are cheap at pick-and-pull yards, have enormous radiative capacity such that they'll probably be able to get by on convection and not need to run a fan, but they also have VERY powerful built-in 12 volt cooling fans, and built-in thermostats.  Add a relay and you already have the 12V.

Comment: cant imagine putting a pc in the refrigerator :D

Comment: A refrigerator uses coils, (under the bottom of the refrig in modern day units, on the back in older refrigerators) to dissipate the heat, not the side skin.  The sides, doors, top and back are all insulated to prevent heat gain.

Comment: @SteveSh I've had several fridges that radiate from their skin. In fact Technology Connections just [did a video on one](https://youtu.be/8PTjPzw9VhY?t=493), and notes that a lot of chest freezers do this too. It's not that hard, attach the condenser to the outer metal skin, *then* have insulation.  No coils to clean!

Answer (score 0):

coolant piped fins and attached 12V case fan *outlet* case fan on fin, fixed to heating core/surface with adhering thermal paste..
Determine the heights of the fin/fan/s to fit in.